# Associating a reference table in sequelize

Tags: mysql, database, orm, relational-database, sequelize.js

I have a couple of tables I'm trying to associate in Sequelize -- a `jobaids_sections_messages` table containing messages a user enters, and a `jobaids_sections_messages_levels` table which is a static reference used by the messages table. They're set up like so

```
this.jobaidMessage = sequelize.define('jobaids_sections_messages', {
    message: Sequelize.STRING,
    attuid: Sequelize.STRING,
    level: Sequelize.INTEGER
}, {
    paranoid: true
});

this.jobaidMessageLevel = sequelize.define('jobaids_sections_messages_levels', {
    name: Sequelize.STRING
}, {
    timestamps: false
});
```

The `jobaids_sections_messages_levels` table is set up like so:

```
| id  |   name   |
| --- | -------- |
| 1   | Critical |
| 2   | Major    |
| 3   | Warning  |
| 4   | Info     |
```

I want to make is so that when I create a new message, I can pass the `level` in as a key to the `jobaids_sections_messages_levels` table, and upon retrieving a message, I get the level back as

```
{
    ...
    level: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Major'
    }
}
```

How should I set my associations up here? So far, I have

```
this.jobaidMessageLevel.belongsTo(this.jobaidMessage, {
    foreignKey: 'level'
});
```

Though I'm not sure about the reversal of this association. Would it be a "many-to-one" relationship of some sorts?

Thank you!

Comment: Please do not deface your post to add an answer. If you have an answer, post it _as an answer_. If you are just thanking someone, _comment on their answer_. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your message has a single level and technically your levels can have many messages. So simply stating that your message `hasOne` level will do the association needed. Then when you pull down a message and include the level, it will come back.

```
this.jobaidMessage.hasOne(this.jobaidMessageLevel, {
    foreignKey: 'levelId'
});
```